# Changing the Order of Integration in this Triple Integral

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

> Evaluate $ \iiint_D (x^2+y^2) \, ,\mathrm{d}V $, where $D$ is the
>   region bounded by the graphs of $y=x^2$, $z=4-y$, and $z=0$.

So after over at least an hour of thinking, I might have all 6 orders of integration. Can someone check my answer please?

1:
$$x=-\sqrt{y}\quad to\quad x=\sqrt{y}\\y=0\quad to\quad y=4\\z=0\quad to\quad z=4-y$$

2:
$$x=-\sqrt{y}\quad to\quad x=\sqrt{y}\\y=0\quad to\quad y=4-z\\z=0\quad to\quad z=4$$

3:
$$y=0\quad to\quad y=4-z\\x=-\sqrt{-z+4}\quad to\quad x=\sqrt{-z+4}\\z=0\quad to\quad z=4$$

4:
$$y=0\quad to\quad y=4-z\\x=-2\quad to\quad x=2\\z=0\quad to\quad z=-x^2+4$$

5:
$$z=0\quad to\quad z=4-y\\x=-2\quad to\quad x=2\\y=x^2\quad to\quad y=4$$

6:
$$z=0\quad to\quad z=4-y\\x=-\sqrt{y}\quad to\quad x=\sqrt{y}\\y=0\quad to\quad y=4$$

Comment: The equations look useful, but do you know in each case which variable needs to be integrated first, second, and last?

Comment: @aschepler: That shouldn't matter just as long the limits of integration of the outer integral(s) don't contain variables of a variable that is being integrated against in an inner integral, right? For example: this would be incorrect: $$\int_0^y\int_0^1ydydx$$

Comment: That's right.  I was just suspicious of your inconsistent way of listing the limits.

Comment: Looks to me like 1, 2, 5, 6 are correct.  3 and 4 both include $(2,0,0)$ in the region $y < x^2$, but $D$ is a piece of $y \geq x^2$.

Comment: Do you happen to know the correct bounds so that I can understand where I went wrong?